.Net 4.8 API using Redis for cache is returning different cache data depending on which site calls it
So my employer has two sites. Both use the same API and that API was recently updated. We added some properties to the return class. These all live in nuget packages. The Redis decorator also lives in one of these packages. One of the two sites got the updated packages for the new fields. One site did not. The cache decorator is on the API call itself, not in the websites.
This isnt really an issue as much as a question on why it worked this way. We know how to fix it, but I want to understand. One website caches the new properties. One site doesnt. And it caused an issue where the two sites were constantly going back and forth like that depending on which made the call first. We fixed this by updating the second site with the new nuget packages.
Why is this? If the cache decorator is on the API call, why wouldn't the cache always contain the new properties, even if the other site didn't know what to do with them yet? I would expect the cache to be exactly the same since both calls come from the same API, but they weren't and I don't understand why.
